# Unable to install docker

Tags: git, bash, docker, hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric

I am trying to do hyperledger fabric(setting up the environment) and it required docker. I tried searching the internet of solving to install docker but it was to no avail. The following is the errors encountered when I tried to install dockers.

At git bash(git) I tried to use `sudo apt-get install docker-engine`. But it says

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable distribution that some required packages have not yet been created or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 Docker-engine: Depends: init-system-helpers (>= 1.13~) but it is not installable
                 Depends: sysv-rc (>= 2.88dsf-24) but 2.88dsf-13.10ubuntu11 is to be installed or
                          file-rc (>= 0.8.16) but it is not installable
                 Depends: libc6 (>= 2.17) but 2.15-0ubuntu10 is to be installed
                 Depends: libdevmapper1.02.1 (>= 2:1.02.63) but 2:1.02.48-4ubuntu7 is to be installed
                 Depends: libsystemd-journal0 (>= 201) but it is not installable
                 Recommends: aufs-tools but it is not going to be installed
                 Recommends: cgroupfs-mount but it is not installable or
                             cgroup-lite but it is not going to be installed
                 Recommends: git but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I have followed every single step of this website in installing docker:
https://docs.docker.com/engine/installation/linux/ubuntulinux/

This is the website I have tried to build hyperledger fabric (At the stage of building outside of vagrant, installing docker):
http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/dev-setup/build/

Comment: You mentioned git bash... are you trying to do this on Windows?

Comment: yeah im trying to do it in window.

Comment: I'm surprised `apt-get` ran! The instructions you're following are for Linux, not Windows. git bash will give you a lot of basic Unix utilities, but it's not Unix. Try these: https://docs.docker.com/engine/installation/windows/

Comment: But if i download docker using window(the link you provided), will it work the same or compatible if im setting up the environment of hyperledger fabric?I'm sorry that im new to setting up hyperledger fabric and docker.

Comment: That I don't know, sorry.

Comment: please read these instruction for setting up hyperledger in windows https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/blob/master/docs/Setup/Chaincode-setup.md#option-2-docker-for-mac-or-windows

Comment: @Schwern its okay thanks alot !

Comment: @SufiyanGhori sorry, am i right to say that if i have vagrant, i dont need docker?

Comment: kind of. You need to install docker inside your vagrant OS not your host (Windows in your case). You need to setup a development environment in your windows with Git client, Go, virtualbox etc, docker has nothing to do with it.

Answer (score 6):

Clean up the invalid package repository:

```
cd ../../etc/apt/sources.list.d
sudo rm docker.list
```

Then add the repository and update:

```
sudo apt-add-repository 'deb https://apt.dockerproject.org/repo ubuntu-xenial main'
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install docker-engine
```

Answer (score 4):

Maybe the [direct package download for `libsystemd-journal0`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/libsystemd-journal0) can help you.

You can download certain deb file then install it using `dpkg` command, but there may still be some dependency problems. So you'd better modify your `/etc/apt/source.list` file according to this [page](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/amd64/libsystemd-journal0/download)(if you need a 64-bit version).

As for `libsystemd-journal0` you can add the following line after the tail of `/etc/apt/sources.list`:

```
deb http://cz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty main
```

then

```
sudo apt-get update
```

I guess other dependency problems can be solved in a similar way.

Comment: This one solved this issue "docker-ce : Depends: libsystemd-journal0 (>= 201) but it is not installable"

Comment: This one solved it for me too, but not directly. I used the default commands in docker website and installed it for the wrong distribution (I'm using Mint). I removed the previous respository and added the one for Xenial (from the actual docker website) and worked.

Answer (score 2):

idk if this works but try this:

```
sudo apt update
```

and,

```
sudo apt-get update
```

then,

```
sudo apt install docker.io
```

Enter your sudo password whenever prompted/required or better login in as root.
I've tried this when i was installing docker in my linux distro. (kali).
Hope this works for you too...
[also try updating your linux distro]

Comment: Please avoid abbreviations (idk) to ensure most people understands.

Answer (score 0):

Update the repos in sourcelist file and run `apt-get update` that will fix the issue,

deb https://packages.docker.com/1.12/apt/repo/ ubuntu-xenial main
  deb http://apt.dockerproject.org/repo/ ubuntu-trusty main

Answer (score -2):

Add backports to your apt repo :
"deb http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian wheezy-backports main"

and perform a :

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Afterwards,

```
sudo apt-get install docker-engine
```

should complete fine.